# Kafka vs. Kafka Connect terminology - Sources & Sinks or Producers & Consumers

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm reading up on Kafka and Kafka Connect. The documentation mentions 'Kafka sources' and 'Kafka sinks' in a generic sort of way in Kafka Connect documentation. I'm not certain if these two terms are specific to Kafka Connect or they are simply referring Producers and Consumers.

Comment: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/concepts.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in need to bring data into your kafka cluster or copy data outside of your kafka ( copy data from / into kafka ) there are many tools supporting you on  that task  ,

You might as well write and MAINTAIN your code with Kafka Consumer / Producer API

In order to avoid struggling to create new code for "already solved problem" kafka community developed the Kafka Connect framework.

the "kafka way" is by leveraging its internal ecosystem tool named kafka connect.
kafka connect is a distributed framework which has many connectors supported by community or vendor. open sourced or proprietary,  there is big and growing hub "market place" for any need.

connector is piece of pluggable code (JAR files) that runs inside the framework, there are two types of connectors , sink connector is "read from kafka and sink to target", and source connector which is "read from data source and write to kafka".
in order to set up a connector you are just setting a configuration file with all the required parameters, without the need of any programming skills. no code. losing some flexibility in favor of simplicity